# Calling a method from GamePanel

Tags: java, swing, java-2d, 2d-games

I believe this is a pretty simple OO question but I can't seem to find the answer :/
I have a game panel where a load of balls are painted onto a panel. When a ball hits the bottom of the panel a Game Over message should be displayed.

The problem which I'm dealing with is regarding this Game Over `JOptionPane`. I believe it should be kept in this class but I need to call it in the `Ball` class.

Here is the part of `Ball` class where I want to call the method (marked with **):

```
private void moveBall() {

    if (x == panel.getWidth() - size) {
        xa -= speed;
    } else if (x < 0) {
        xa += speed;
    }

    if (y == panel.getHeight() - size) {
        ya -= speed;
    } else if (y < 0) {
        ya += speed;
    }

    if (collision()) {
        ya = -speed;
        y = platform.getY() - DIAMETER;
    }

    if (y == panel.getHeight() - size) {

        // ***Call gameOver here***

    }
    x += xa;
    y += ya;
}
```

Here is the constructor being called from the ball class in my game panel:

```
// Constructor to pass a colour and a platform
public Ball(JFrame frame, JPanel panel, Platform platform, Color colour,
        int x, int y, int size) {

    this.platform = platform;

    this.frame = frame;
    this.panel = panel;
    this.colour = colour;

    // Location of the ball
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

    // Size of the ball
    this.size = size;

    animator = new Thread(this);
    animator.start();
}
```

So how do I get access to that method?

Note (Structure): Frame -> Panel -> Ball

Thanks

Let me know if I haven't explained myself well or you need more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider watching the position of the ball from a different class, which has access to the gameOver function. This way you don't need to expose the panels to the `Ball` class, and your problem is avoided.

Also, you can't call the `gameOver` function since it does not exist in `JFrame`, if you want to use this current approach, you need to supply the class, or an interface, which contains the `gameOver` function to the `Ball` constructor.

Comment: so wouldn't I need to create a new instant of the GamePanel in that class then and then create an instance of that class in the ball class?

Comment: If you create the GamePanel once, you can pass it along wherever you'd like. You don't have to re-create it.

Comment: Such a simple question with such a simple answer when I actually stopped to think about how java works. Done. Thanks for that lol

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having your `Ball` class call a method from your `Frame` or `Panel` class, I think the better way to achieve what you want is to have a method in your `Ball` class that indicates/sets a boolean for if your ball has hit the bottom of the screen. Then have this method fire when the ball touches the bottom of the screen (where you want to place the game over method call currently).

From there, have the class that has access to your gameover method check this indicator/boolean for whether or not it should fire the game over method.